# ipconfig - Get all the connected USB device's IP address

Tags: windows-7, command-line, ipconfig

In Ubuntu, ifconfig lists all the USB devices with the header "usb0, usb1, ..etc"

I need to know the IP addresses of all the connected USB devices. It would be really helpful if on Windows ipconfig displayed the same thing...but it doesn't.

Is there any way to get this information? (doesn't have to be ipconfig, but needs to be some sort of cmd prompt command)

Thanks

Comment: Can you also provide Win version?

Comment: You can list all USB devices with something like this: gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | Sort Description,DeviceID | ft Description,DeviceID -auto in PowerShell

Comment: What's gwmi? You need to be more descriptive, I'm hoping to use things that come with Windows

Comment: If you need more info for [Get WMI](http://ss64.com/ps/get-wmiobject.html) and using with [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb978526.aspx)

Comment: OK I did that command but it doesn't list the IP addresses, just the devices (I see my device and its device id...)

Comment: what about MAC addresses, would those do ? If you do add IPAddress before the "auto" separated with comma from DeviceID does not work. Mayebe someone has a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get IP addresses of network devices that are attached to your PC you can run the following command in PowerShell:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE
```

This should display IP Address, Description and other info for you.

Sample of the results courtesy of ITProGuru

[image]

To get all USB devices you can type in the following in PowerShell:

```
gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | Sort Description,DeviceID | ft Description,DeviceID -auto
```

To get the final result you need to cross reference or maybe some one that is more familiar with PowerShell can shed some light on that.

Comment: Thanks this might work. All my devices have similar Descriptions, so is there a way to filter the list based off of that? It might be the easiest way. Also Their Service Names all say "usb_rndisx" so that could also be a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is possible only if they are detected by the OS as **network cards**. In that case, `ipconfig /all` solves the problem. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Yes, the devices are listed in the Device Manager as Network adapters. When I do ipconfig I see the device listed, but how do I extract only the IP? And how do I get only the USB devices? (ie: Network Adapters connected via USB)

Comment: I figured out how to get the ip address. For example on a mac ...  once a device like a phone is trusted and connected with usb a new interface shows from the command `ipconfig getiflist` ... in my case this showed the network interface `en10`. Then I run ifconfig and it lists the ip addresses for all interfaces and the en10 network interface in the ifconfig output shows the inet value which is the ipv4 address.